# How to set width of a button bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to set custom width of a bootstrap button.

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to shrink width of button to like on the image (it's a submit button). Left part is input text. My problem is button is too wide. Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg input-forme" id="Text" placeholder="Text">
    <span class="input-group-btn tipka">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-group-small" id="form-submit">Submit</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change width and padding : https://jsfiddle.net/wz8ac5d4/

```
.btn {
    width:0px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Also you can add a class to your btn, it is a better practice.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-group-small my-small-btn" id="form-submit">Submit</button>
```

**CSS :**

```
.my-small-btn {
    width:0px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Dont overwrite `.btn` directly unless you want to change the style for all bootstrap buttons. A better solution would be to add another class to the button and make sure your custom CSS file is below the bootstrap CSS in page `head`.

Answer (score 0):

The classes that define the different sizes are:

.btn-lg
.btn-md
.btn-sm
.btn-xs

refer  this link

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp

Comment: I'd like to add these classes will also alter the height.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase its size with this:

```
.btn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used max-width with padding.

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn custom-btn" id="form-submit">Submit</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-btn {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-right:25px;
}
```

You can also just shortcut the padding.

```
.custom-btn {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 25px;
}
```

Just adjust the 25px to whatever length you want to get the appropriate size.

Please note that 6px is the standard top and bottom padding for a medium bootstrap button.  You will have to adjust accordingly for large and small buttons.